# Core Foundation Framework Error in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, core-foundation

I am attempting to call the  CFSwapInt32HostToBig(<#arg: UInt32#>) method in swift file. I have added the CoreFoundation Framework to the project and I have "import CoreFoundation" at the top of my swift file. When I begin to type the method name, XCode suggest the method indicating to me that Xcode is recognizing methods from that framework. I have no errors in Xcode implying that all of my syntax is correct, but when I build I get the following error.

```
> Ld DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AudioToy.app/AudioToy normal x86_64
    cd /Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Intermediates/AudioToy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AudioToy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AudioToy.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Intermediates/AudioToy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AudioToy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AudioToy.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework CoreFoundation -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Intermediates/AudioToy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AudioToy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AudioToy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/michaliberman/Documents/Projects/Swift/AudioToy/DerivedData/AudioToy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AudioToy.app/AudioToy

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CASwapFloat32", referenced from:
      _CASwapFloat32HostToBig in AudioStudio.o
  "__OSSwapInt32", referenced from:
      _CFSwapInt32HostToBig in AudioStudio.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have removed and re-imported the framework, but I still get the error. When I option-click on the method name it shows me the header file in which the method is declared and it if I click on that header file I see that it is within the framework. I am not sure what to do when the problem appears to be within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bigEndian` and `littleEndian` methods

```
let valueLE16 = 16
let valueBE16 = valueLE16.bigEndian

println("valueLE16: \(valueLE16)") // valueLE16: 16
println("valueBE16: \(valueBE16)") // valueBE16: 1152921504606846976

let valueLE16: Int16 = 16 //UnsafePointer<UInt16>(value.bytes)[0]
let valueBE16: Int16 = valueLE16.bigEndian

println("valueLE16: \(valueLE16)") // valueLE16: 16
println("valueBE16: \(valueBE16)") // valueBE16: 4096
```